# Need to get my site to be the same as the code pen version

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have never asked a question here before but am struggling to recreate the same alignment from code pen to my code.  I have tried a number of different ways to change it

Apologies if the format is wrong.

[Code pen version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KOdj1.jpg) 
[my version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qxcbl.jpg)

```
    <!doctype html>
<html class="html">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="V3index.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Vertebrae index</title>
<script src="/path/to/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('.grid').masonry({
  itemSelector: '.grid-item',
  columnWidth: 1
});
</script>


</head>


<body class="body" bgcolor="#650373">

<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-border--colour1"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-border--colour2"></div>

  <div class="grid-item grid-border--colour4"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-border--colour5"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-border--colour6  grid-item--width2 "></div>
</div>






</body>
</html>

@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */


/* ---- grid-item ---- */
.grid {
        position: relative;
        top: 20%;
        max-width: 600px;
        min-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}




/* clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  width: 260px;
  float: left;
  border: 6px solid;
}

.grid-border--colour1 { border-color: #ea45ad; margin: 4px; height: 250px;}
.grid-border--colour2 { border-color: #d5d163; margin: 4px; height: 150px;}

.grid-border--colour4 { border-color: #0abb2f; margin: 4px; height: 250px;}
.grid-border--colour5 { border-color: #d27bdc; margin: 4px; height: 150px;}
.grid-border--colour6 { border-color: #e47d32; margin: 4px; height: 200px;}



.grid-item--width2 { width: 530px; }


.grid-item--height1 { height: 644px; }
```

Comment: Post the codepen link, an image is useless

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your initialization for Masonry to this,

```
var msnry = new Masonry( '.grid', {
  columnWidth: 1,
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
```

You can see a working example here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EPrvgO

The following html works in IE Edge and Chrome 48;

```
<html class="html">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="V3index.css">
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
<title>Vertebrae index</title>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/masonry/4.0.0/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body class="body" bgcolor="#650373">
<style>
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

* { box-sizing: border-box; }

body { font-family: sans-serif; }

/* ---- grid ---- */


/* ---- grid-item ---- */
.grid {
        position: relative;
        top: 20%;
        max-width: 600px;
        min-width: 400px;
        margin: 0 auto;
}




/* clearfix */
.grid:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}

/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
  width: 260px;
  float: left;
  border: 6px solid;
}

.grid-border--colour1 { border-color: #ea45ad; margin: 4px; height: 250px;}
.grid-border--colour2 { border-color: #d5d163; margin: 4px; height: 150px;}

.grid-border--colour4 { border-color: #0abb2f; margin: 4px; height: 250px;}
.grid-border--colour5 { border-color: #d27bdc; margin: 4px; height: 150px;}
.grid-border--colour6 { border-color: #e47d32; margin: 4px; height: 200px;}



.grid-item--width2 { width: 530px; }


.grid-item--height1 { height: 644px; }
</style>
<div class="grid">
  <div class="grid-item grid-border--colour1"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-border--colour2"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-border--colour4"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-border--colour5"></div>
  <div class="grid-item grid-border--colour6  grid-item--width2 "></div>
</div>
<script>
var msnry = new Masonry( '.grid', {
  columnWidth: 1,
  itemSelector: '.grid-item'
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, it seems that the code displays fine in code pen but doesn't render in browser (or dreamwever)

Comment: I cant show you a screenshot as my reputation is low.

Comment: Can anyone help?Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much, I had the JS script in the wrong part of the html thank you for your patience and help.